# List and += operation

Tags: python, list

I'm using the `list` object by declaring

```
data = []
```

in my code, and without initializing it, I wrote

```
data += data2
```

Where `data2` is another `list` that contains lots of numbers.

An error happened at this line:

```
local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: is there a way to declare data to be NULL like C/C++?

Comment: show more code. it seems you use ` data += data2` in function but you forgot to use `global data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using `data.extend (data2)` instead of using the operator.

See this question for an extended discussion about adding two lists together: [Python: take the content of a list and append it to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177079/python-take-the-content-of-a-list-and-append-it-to-another-list)

Comment: this answer doesn't address the question.  it makes no sense that using `extend` instead of `+=` would prevent the error.  @CHEN has left out important information about where these lines of code have been placed in his script or module.

Comment: @dbliss It seems the asker disagrees ;)

Comment: @dbliss I did misread the question though, however I left the answer because I thought it might point to a more flexible way to merge lists.

Comment: what's "more flexible" about `extend`?  all it does is add overhead.  i'd be interested to know of any case where using `extend` makes more sense than using `+=`.

Answer (score 3):

Getting 'referenced before assignment' after you initializing data can't happen if you are in the same scope.

The possibility is that you are creating a function (creating a new scope) so when you say `data+=data2` it means

```
data = data + data2 # so what is data in the right hand side?
```

So if you want to refer the global variable use already available (global) data you have to explicitly say `global data` or pass that as a parameter to the funciton.

Comment: I accurately did create a new function! So that's where goes wrong. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your array first. Here is a working example of how to fix this problem.

```
data = [0]
data2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
print data
data += data2
print data
```

Comment: you can use `data = []` in place of  `data=[0]` and still works

Answer (score 0):

If you use `data += data2` in function you need `global data`

```
data = []
data2 = [1,2,3,4]

def add():
    globla data

    data += data2

add()
print data
```

or send `data` as argument

```
data = []
data2 = [1,2,3,4]

def add(some_data):
    some_data += data2

add(data)
print data
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is covered in the docs here

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**iadd**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__)

> For instance, if `x` is an instance of a class with an `__iadd__()`
>   method, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)` .

So you see `data` is being rebound (to itself in this case), but it still counts as an assignment.

Since `data += data2` appears inside a function scope where `data` has not been declared to be `global`, a local variable called `data` is assumed.

```
def foo():
    data.extend(data2)           # ok -- global data variable here

def bar():
    data = data.__iadd__(data2)  # not ok -- local data variable here

def baz():
    data += data2                # not ok -- equivalent to bar()
```