# python: append() to a single list of list appends to all

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a lists of list, and I would like to append data to each sublist independently.  When I append to one, it seems like ALL of the sublists are getting the same data appended.  Here is my code:

Code:

```
parent = [[]] * 2
data = [1]*4
parent[0].append(data)
print "sublist 0:", parent[0]
print "sublist 1:", parent[1]
```

Output:

```
sublist 0: [[1, 1, 1, 1]]
sublist 1: [[1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Expected Output:

```
sublist 0: [[1, 1, 1, 1]]
sublist 1: []
```

What am I doing wrong or not understanding here?

Comment: I think this post may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177079/python-take-the-content-of-a-list-and-append-it-to-another-list

Comment: Jimmy, My question is a duplicate, all the answers there will help me.  To change my code all I need to do is `parent = [[] for _ in range(2)]`

Comment: Initiating is different from constructing.

     a = [[]] * 2  # here initiated a list and assigned to a.
     b = [[] for _ in range(2)]  # here constructing a list and assigning to b.