# Concatenating 2 dimensional numpy arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

I want to concatenate these two arrays

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])  
b = np.array([9,10,11])
```

such that

```
a = [[1,2,3,9],[3,4,5,10],[6,7,8,11]]
```

Tried using concatenate

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  a[i] = np.concatenate(a[i],[b[i]])
```

Got an error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Tried using append

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  a[i] = np.append(a[i],b[i])
```

Got another error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,) into shape (3,)
```

(New to stackoverflow, sorry if I didn't format this well)

Comment: You can use [**`extend()`**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/): possible duplicate of [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177079/take-the-content-of-a-list-and-append-it-to-another-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate a NumPy array to another NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/concatenate-a-numpy-array-to-another-numpy-array)

Comment: seems like extend() only works for list. I can convert them to lists, extend them, then convert it back to a numpy array. But there gotta be a better way to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`hstack`** and vector broadcasting for that:

```py
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])  
b = np.array([9,10,11])
res = np.hstack((a, b[:,None]))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2  3  9]
 [ 3  4  5 10]
 [ 6  7  8 11]]
```

Note that you cannot use `concatenate` because the array have *different shapes*. `hstack` stack horizontally the *multi-dimentional* arrays so it just add a new line at the end here. A broadcast operation (`b[:,None]`) is needed so that the appended vector is a vertical one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
np.append(a,b.reshape(-1,1),axis=1)
```