# Unexpected result when using list.append(). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, list

I can't understand the following two examples of behaviour of `list.append()` in Python:

```
list_1 = ['A', 'B']
list_2 = ['C', 'D']

copy_l1 = list_1
copy_l1.append(list_2)
```

1. Example

   ```
   print(copy_l1)
   ```

   result: `['A', 'B', ['C', 'D']]`

   expected: `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.

   I kind of understand this, but how to get the expected result?
2. Example

   ```
   print(list_1)
   ```

   result: `['A', 'B', ['C', 'D']]`

   expected: `['A', 'B']`.

This is the most puzzling for me. Why does `copy_l1.append(list_2)` also affect `list_1`? Due to my backgound in C, this looks to me like I'm working on pointers, but I gather that should not be the case. What means?

Comment: `copy_l1 = list_1` doesn't make a copy of the list. Both variables reference the same list.

Comment: Use `copy_l1 = list_1.copy()`

Comment: for the first one, you want `list.extend`: `copy_l1.extend( list_2 )`

Comment: See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take the content of a list and append it to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177079/take-the-content-of-a-list-and-append-it-to-another-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first result is expected as you are adding the list itself, not its values, to `copy_l1`. To get the desired result, use either of the following:

- `copy_l1 += list2`
- `copy_l1.extend(list2)`

---

The second result is harder to understand, but it has to do with the fact that lists are mutable in Python. To understand this, you must first understand what actually happens when you assign one variable to another.

### Variable Assignment

When you use `var_a = var_b`, both names point to the same variable - that is, the same space in memory; they are just two different ways of accessing it. This can be tested using `is`, which checks for identity, not just value:

```py
a = 1
b = a
print(a is b)
# True
```

So you would expect that changing the value of one name would also affect the other. However, this is not usually the case.

### Changing the Value of an Immutable Variable

Most basic data types in Python are **immutable**. This means that their value can't actually be changed once they are created. Some examples of immutable data types are `str`s, `int`s, `float`s and `bool`s.

If the data type of a variable is immutable, then its value can't be changed directly. Instead, when you alter the value of a name pointing it, this is what actually happens:

1. A new variable is created
2. Its value is set to the new value
3. It is given the same name as the name which you are trying to alter - it effectively replaces it

During this process, only one name has had its value changed (or rather, replaced) and any other names pointing to the same variable stay unchanged. You can test that the actual variable the name points to has changed using `is`:

```py
a = 5
b = a
print(a is b)
# True
a += 4
print(a is b)
# False
```

Because of this, the fact that variable assignment works the way it does can almost always be ignored. But this changes when you use mutable variables, such as `list`s.

### Changing the Value of a Mutable Variable

Because lists are mutable, their value can actually be changed so this three-step process is not necessary. Therefore, all names pointing to the list get changed. You can see this by using `is` once again:

```py
a = [1, 2]
b = a
print(a is b)
# True
a += [3, 4]
print(a is b, "again")
# True again
```

### How to Stop this Happening

To stop this from happening, use `.copy()` to get a shallow copy of the list:

```py
copy_l1 = list1.copy()
```

Now both names point to different variables, which happen to have the same value. Operations on one will not affect the other.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! Your explanation of mutable/immutable variables really helped me

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `.extend()` rather than `.append()` to concatenate lists.

```
copy_l1.extend(list_2)
```

2. You didn't make a copy of `list_1`, both variables refer to the same list. Use

```
copy_l1 = list_1.copy()
```

to make a shallow copy of `list_1`.

Comment: I'd have thought that of all the answerers here you'd have known there'd be a zillion duplicates of this question already. You could trivially have dupe hammered it.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_1 = ['A', 'B']
list_2 = ['C', 'D']

copy_l1 = list_1
copy_l1.extend( list_2 )
#or
copy_l1+=list_2
```

Answer (score 2):

You use wrong ways of concatenating and coping lists.

To concatenate lists you can:

```
copy_l1.extend(list_2)
copy_l1 += list_2
```

To copy list you can:

```
copy_l1 = list_1.copy()
copy_l1 = list_1[:]
copy_l1 = list(list_1)
```