# Adding all elements from list into json dict

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a list with a couple nested elements in it. For example:

```py
list=[{'new1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
     {'new2': {'bar': [{'type': 'bar', 'bar': {'content': 'bar'}}]}}]
```

I also have a dict for some json data I need to submit via `requests`.

For example, this works just fine

```py
json_data={
  "parent": { "foo": "bar" },
  "children": [
      {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}}
  ]
}

requests.post(url, headers=common_headers, data=json.dumps(json_data))
```

What I'm trying to do is add all elements from the `list` into the `json_data`. For example, if I add a single element from the list, it works fine

```py
json_data={
  "parent": { "foo": "bar" },
  "children": [
      {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      list[0]
  ]
}
```

Because it turns into this

```py
json_data={
  "parent": { "foo": "bar" },
  "children": [
      {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      {'new1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}}
  ]
}
```

However, if I add the entire list, it includes the brackets `[]` and fails. For example, this:

```py
json_data={
  "parent": { "foo": "bar" },
  "children": [
      {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      list
  ]
}
```

Turns into

```py
json_data={
  "parent": { "foo": "bar" },
  "children": [
      {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      [
          {'new1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
          {'new2': {'bar': [{'type': 'bar', 'bar': {'content': 'bar'}}]}}
      ]
  ]
}
```

The square brackets are breaking the request. Because I don't know how many elements will be in the list, I can't define which element to use (like in the first example).

Is there an easy way for me to include all elements of the list, without the square brackets?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take the content of a list and append it to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177079/take-the-content-of-a-list-and-append-it-to-another-list)

Comment: Just use `json_data['children'].extend(list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and simple way to keep it, from Python 3.9 (i mean) you can use *list to extend it on the fly, like this code here.

```
json_data={
  "parent": { "foo": "bar" },
  "children": [
      {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      *list
  ]
}
```

its return a dict like this.

```
{
    'parent': {
        'foo': 'bar'
    },
    'children': [{
        'existing1': {
            'foo': [{
                'type': 'foo',
                'foo': {
                    'content': 'foo'
                }
            }]
        }
    }, {
        'existing2': {
            'foo': [{
                'type': 'foo',
                'foo': {
                    'content': 'foo'
                }
            }]
        }
    }, {
        'new1': {
            'foo': [{
                'type': 'foo',
                'foo': {
                    'content': 'foo'
                }
            }]
        }
    }, {
        'new2': {
            'bar': [{
                'type': 'bar',
                'bar': {
                    'content': 'bar'
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpack the list into its destination

```
json_data = {
    "parent": {"foo": "bar"},
    "children": [
        {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
        {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
        *values
    ]
}
```

Or use `list.extend`

```
json_data = {
    "parent": {"foo": "bar"},
    "children": [
        {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
        {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
    ]
}
json_data['children'].extend(values)
```

---

Don't use builtin `list` keyword for your variable, that's the list constructor

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple way

only use '+'

ex)

```
    json_data={
  "parent": { "foo": "bar" },
  "children": [
      {'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
      {'existing2': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}}
  ]
}
```

and have a list that I want to add

```
list_ =      [
          {'new1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
          {'new2': {'bar': [{'type': 'bar', 'bar': {'content': 'bar'}}]}}
      ]
```

and

```
json_data['children'] += list_
```

result

```
[{'existing1': {'foo': [{'foo': {'content': 'foo'}, 'type': 'foo'}]}},
 {'existing2': {'foo': [{'foo': {'content': 'foo'}, 'type': 'foo'}]}},
 {'new1': {'foo': [{'foo': {'content': 'foo'}, 'type': 'foo'}]}},
 {'new2': {'bar': [{'bar': {'content': 'bar'}, 'type': 'bar'}]}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different to other answers as this allows for more entries in the original list:

```
list_ = [{'new1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}},
         {'new2': {'bar': [{'type': 'bar', 'bar': {'content': 'bar'}}]}}]

json_data = {"parent": {"foo": "bar"}, "children": []}

for dl in list_:
    for i, v in enumerate(dl.values(), 1):
        json_data["children"].append({f'existing{i}': v})

print(json_data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'parent': {'foo': 'bar'}, 'children': [{'existing1': {'foo': [{'type': 'foo', 'foo': {'content': 'foo'}}]}}, {'existing1': {'bar': [{'type': 'bar', 'bar': {'content': 'bar'}}]}}]}
```