# How to add a list to another list as a list

Tags: python, list, append

I have multiple lists like below

```
x = []
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 5]
```

I am trying to append a and b to x and get a result like below

```
print(x)
#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

But I have no idea how to do this task. Append or other things just makes it like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] which i don't want to. Is there any methods in python for that or should I use some other packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take the content of a list and append it to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177079/take-the-content-of-a-list-and-append-it-to-another-list)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out there is a method called insert for that... Sorry i am a newbie. Problem solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use append method try this:

```
l = []
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 5]

l.append(a)
print(l)
l.append(b)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `append` to insert any `object` in list including list. list is an `object` so you can simply do that an it'll work

```
>>> x = []
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 5]
>>> x.append(a)
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> x.append(b)
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use from this code:

```py
x = [a, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
x = []
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 5]

x += [a, b]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 5]]
```